# Apache Rewrite: secondary htaccess for domain specific RedirectMatch

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

On shared web-hosting my software supports multiple domains (all domains point to the same public_html root directory).

What I want to do is keep redirects (and any RedirectMatch) in their own host specific/dedicated .htaccess file.

Visually the directory structure looks like this...

> /public_html/ (all domains are pointed internally to this directory)
>
> /public_html/.htaccess
>
> /public_html/www.example1.com/
>
> /public_html/www.example2.com/
>
> /public_html/www.example3.com/

There are two approaches I'm considering though would appreciate input from others:

The first would be to keep domain specific redirects out of the main .htaccess file as defined above. So I'd like to have redirects handled by the .htaccess files as defined by below if possible...

> /public_html/www.example1.com/.htaccess
>
> /public_html/www.example2.com/.htaccess
>
> /public_html/www.example3.com/.htaccess

...if this is not feasible I'll settle for a rewrite to a PHP file to hand off redirects to PHP instead. I imagine this isn't as performance oriented though on the other hand it would give me the opportunity to log redirects and see how long it takes them to level off.

Some clarifications:

1. I'm using shared web hosting so anything Apache related needs to be done through .htaccess files only.
2. There are no redirects/matches in the master .htaccess file nor will there ever be since two domains may eventually attempt to use the same redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are on shared host, You cannot afford to have any solutions concerning conf files (which BTW are better). So wont bother to list them. Best way to do the above is like this:

*The code was written keeping in mind that none of the domains share any kind of file/data on the server. Every file/data pertaining to a domain is kept under a folder having the name equal to its domainname.*

#### The code below is tested(both static and non static):

```
RewritEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

And add either of the following to the above:

**for doing it statically:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example1|example2|example3)(\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.%1%2/$1 [L]
```

**for doing it statically: and also if you want to access the site without `www`**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(example1|example2|example3)(\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1%2%3/$1 [L]
```

**for Non-statically do it: this is a better sol**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

All the above will do is redirect URI to their specific domain's folder. All other domain specific rewrites can be handled in the respective folders.

If you have URIs without the www, i.e. `example1.com` change `^www\.(example1|example2|example3)(\.com)$` to `^(www\.)?(example1|example2|example3)(\.com)$`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm working on testing this out however you statically defined the domain names, I'm not going to manually edit domains in to the master .htaccess file every single time I add a new site so I've got to rewrite your answer to use %{HTTP_HOST} instead of static domain names (example1, example2, etc should not be in the code at all).

Comment: Tried your static code and it completely destroys all other rewrites, can't use and I'm unable to find anything about REDIRECT_STATUS. Perhaps the code should be for 404 requests to be offhanded only. Because it severely impacts all other rewrites I have to vote-down your answer for now (only to discourage people from using code that I know breaks) though if you correct it and help me get it working I'll completely reverse that.

Comment: @John do you mean you have done what I have just updated in the answer?

Comment: @John What other redirects do you have? and also this is the nest way to do it! Its not the problem with the Rewrites rules in the answer above. The rewrite rules are fine!

Comment: @John Just to make sure, I tested(both static and non static version) it here. There is definitely no problem with the Rewrite Rules!!!!!!

Comment: Did some reading trying to find a way to match ONLY 404... RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Let's rework the code using those conditions...think that is a good route?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7902/discussion-between-thinkingmonkey-and-john)

Comment: @John Do you have any files(that you serve) in your `public_html/`, are those used by all the domains/some domain?

Comment: @John also explain what do you mean by `404` errors you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, up-voted to negate my earlier down-vote; will go with the PHP rewrite to handle redirects, can log what redirects are utilized I suppose. Thanks again!